# Botão não chama função corretamente

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

class Application:

      def __init__(self, master=None):
          self.inicio = Frame(master)
          self.inicio.pack()
          self.msg = Label(self.inicio, text="Deseja exprimentar a versao input?")
          self.msg["font"] = ("Calibri", "9", "italic")
          self.msg.pack ()
          self.sim = Button(self.inicio)
          self.sim["text"] = "sim"
          self.sim["font"] = ("Calibri", "9")
          self.sim["width"] = 10
          self.sim.bind("<Button-1>", self.Verificar)
          self.sim.pack ()
          self.nao = Button(self.inicio)
          self.nao["text"] = "nao"
          self.nao["font"] = ("Calibri", "9")
          self.nao["width"] = 10
          self.nao.bind("<Button-2>", self.Verificar)
          self.nao.pack ()

      def Verificar(self, event):
          if self.msg["text"] == "Deseja exprimentar a versao input?":
              self.msg["text"] = "Bem vindo a versao de input"

          else:
              self.msg['text']='Deseja exprimentar a versao input?'

root = Tk()

Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Alguém me explica como faço para quando carregar no não aparecer a mensagem 'Bem vindo a versão output'?

Comment: Bom, você tá criando o `Label` no construtor com essa frase (quer dizer, com "input" nela), então é natural que ele apareça desde já. Vc pode colocar outro texto (vazio `""`, talvez) no label de início, por exemplo.

Comment: Eu queria que quando carregasse no não que a frase mude para bem vindo a versão output e n estou a conseguir so aparece quando carrego a segunda vez no sim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste trecho:

```
self.nao.bind("<Button-2>", self.Verificar)
```

`<Button-2>` se refere ao botão do meio do mouse (experimente o seu programa como está, clicando com o botão do meio).

Sem mexer muito no seu programa, eu adicionaria uma nova função:

```
  def Verificar(self, event): # removi o else dessa
          self.msg["text"] = "Bem vindo a versao de input"
  def Verificar2(self, event): # função nova
          self.msg["text"] = "Bem vindo a versao de output"
```

E mudaria o código do botão `nao` para `<Button-1>` também:

```
self.nao.bind("<Button-1>", self.Verificar2)
```

> Isso deve fazer o que você quer, usando os botões corretos... :)

Comment: muito obrigado :) resolvido agora sim posso prosseguir no meu projeto

Comment: :D Quando puder, @GhostCode, marque a resposta como 'aceita', clicando na marca de verificação do lado esquerdo do texto!

Comment: já agora sabe me explicar como faço para quando carregar sim apareça uma tabela para inserir valores já fiz a estrutura toda da tabela ect... mas n consigo fazer com que  abra a tabela n sei com fazer a ligação entre a primeira parte e a segunda . tenho de realizar um ciclo de for? ou um if ?

Comment: @GhostCode Sugiro que você abra uma pergunta sobre isso, e inclua o seu código! Eu juro que te diria se soubesse :(

Comment: muito obrigada na mesma já actualizei uma perguntar anterior sobre o programa que estava a fazer vou ver se alguém me consegue ajudar :)

Comment: @GhostCode Vou dar uma olhada! Acho muito legal que você já esteja partindo para um programa com GUI (interface gráfica) mas sugiro que você tente fazê-lo em `console` primeiro (pesquise por programa de console), e depois, com um programa básico funcionando desta maneira, tente implementar um GUI para ele.

Comment: obrigado pelo concelho e ajuda mas tem de ser mesmo aqui porque depois de conseguir concluir  vou ter de apresentar numa aula .:)